# Magento using setLocale and translation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to force certain text to use the  Dutch translation.

config.xml:

```
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Starmall_Config>
                <files>
                    <default>Starmall.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Starmall_Config>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
```

starmall.csv:

```
"Domestic", "Binnenland"
```

test.php:

```
<?php
    define("MAGE_BASE_DIR", "/home/users/bolovftp/dev.bolout.nl");
    require_once MAGE_BASE_DIR . '/app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);


    Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale('nl_NL')->init('frontend', true);
    print Mage::helper('starmall_config')->__("Domestic");
?>
```

This prints this:

```
{{{Binnenland}}{{Binnenland}}{{Domestic}}{{Starmall_Config}}}
```

Why does it do this? I just want it to print `Binnenland`

**=== ADDED INFO ===**

helper declaration:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <starmall_config>
          <class>Starmall_Config_Helper</class>
        </starmall_config>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

path to csv:

```
../app/locale/nl_NL/Starmall.csv
```

Using translations from this file works fine. Only I set the locale in the admin backend using the locale combobox on the bottom left of the page.

Comment: can you show us the helper's declaration in your config.xml? and also the content (at least the part containing the string you're trying to translate) of Starmall.csv? and show us the path of this csv file

Comment: I added extra info. I already added the translation key content at the top below the config.xml part. On the admin page there is a combobox with the languages. When I set this to Dutch the translations are picked up from my csv file.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what the problem is here